# Unresolved Reference when importing Python Classes

Tags: python, oop, pycharm

So firstly for my project I am using pycharm. In my project I use Tkinter GUIs.

To keep my code short I have taken the class for one window out of my main folder called `main.py` and moved to another folder called `login_gui`. The class is called `UserLogin`.

Then on my `main.py` I attempt to import the class using the code `from login_gui import UserLogin` however on both `login_gui` and `UserLogin` I get a "Unresolved Reference" error.

I have tried putting a . in front of `login_gui` so it reads `from .login_gui import UserLogin`. This removes the reference Errors however when I then run the code I get an error saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Tom/.PyCharmCE2016.3/Project/A-Level_CS/main.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .login_gui import UserLogin
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.login_gui'; '__main__' is not a package
```

This is a custom class and I can't figure how to import as you would any other addons for python, using the python interpreter. Any help would be appreciated thank you.

Comment: Can you provide your whole folder structure

Comment: are you sure the file that you are trying to import is in some sub-directory and you didn't import it in you __init__.py?

Comment: @MisterMonk https://gyazo.com/2422eec5c03ba092e14734d2cd27ef38 will that be helpful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your folder/file structure looks like

```
C:/Users/Tom/.PyCharmCE2016.3/Project/A-Level_CS/
  main.py
  login_gui.py
```

then `from login_gui ...` is correct and `from .login_gui ...` is not (as it would imply `A-Level_CS` to be a Python package, and it's not).

However, you'll need to add the `A-Level_CS` folder as a Sources Root, so PyCharm knows how to resolve these references.  The easiest way to do this is to right-click the folder in the Project view, then select Mark Directory As -> Sources Root:

[image]

Another option, of course, is to create/open a PyCharm project directly in the `A-Level_CS` directory.

Answer (score 0):

AKX Solution is correct, but try to work with packages, it makes some stuff easier.

https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/modules.html#packages

[image]